# getApplicationContext() with AppWidgetProvider

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget, android-context

I'm trying to connect my `Widget` to the app's database, but I don't understand a thing.
Why this works:

```
import android.app.Activity;
public class Widgets1 extends Activity{
mMioDbHelper = new SqlHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

and this not?

```
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
public class Widgets1 extends AppWidgetProvider{
mMioDbHelper = new SqlHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

How can I connect the widget to the database? I mean how can I do a query from a widget class?

Thanks.

Comment: widget is not an activity. the main purpose of widget is to display often used functions that the user can trigger right from the home screen.

Comment: @Libin the question was another: how can I do a query from a widget class? I know it can be done... Thanks :)

Comment: `getContentResolver()`

Comment: @Blundell it doesn't work with `AppWidgetProvider` :(

Comment: SOLVED using `context.getApplicationContext()`, thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AppWidgetProvider` extends `BroadcastReceiver`, which does not, in turn, inherit from `Context`. `getApplicationContext()` is a method on `Context`. As you determined, the reason why you are passed a `Context` into `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver` (and `onUpdate()` and other callbacks on `AppWidgetProvider`) is so you can do things that need a `Context`.

All that being said, the code you have here has issues:

1. Do not use methods inherited from `Context` from an initializer, as you have with your `Activity` snippet. There is no guarantee that such methods are ready for use at that point in time. Delay using `Context` methods until the initial entry point of the component, such as `onCreate()` of an `Activity`.
2. Never do database I/O on the main application thread, as it will freeze your application's UI if one of your activities happens to be in the foreground at the time. All callbacks to your `AppWidgetProvider`, like `onUpdate()`, are called on the main application thread. Please use an `IntentService` or something else that can safely run a background thread. Note that the `IntentService` is perfectly capable of updating the app widget UI via `AppWidgetManager`. `onUpdate()` is a *trigger* for you to do certain work, but that work can -- and often times should -- be done elsewhere.
3. Be very careful in creating all sorts of `SQLiteOpenHelper` instances, and I am assuming that `SqlHelper` is a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Please have exactly *one* instance of  your `SQLiteOpenHelper` for your entire application, so that you can take advantage of the thread safety built into `SQLiteOpenHelper`. That usually winds up being a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Having multiple instances is likely to get you in thread-related trouble.